# How do you put vertical lines in between DataGrid Headers in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, I'm trying to just put vertical lines in the Headers - just like the datagrid has the feature to put vertical and horizontal gridlines in.. But how in the world can I put GridLines to separate the Headers? Right now I have

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataGridColumnHeader` is a `ButtonBase`, you can style its `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` to achieve what you want, also you may want the header to be center, so we also need to set `HorizontalContentAlignment`:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />                    
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />                    

        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/> 
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
     </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the HeaderTemplate. A quick way to do this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                            Header="{Binding HeaderName}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" 
                            BorderBrush="Black">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                   Margin="5"/>                            
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```